# Synaptic - How can I search in only my installed programs?

Tags: synaptic

I want to use Synaptic Package Manager to search for a keyword and list all packages that contain that keyword in the name or description of the package. I can search for keywords in synaptic, but this shows both installed and not installed packages in a list. How can I search for a package, and only list ones that are installed? When I click **status** and list all installed packages, and then try to search, I only get the same list with both installed and not installed packages.

Comment: The answer I got below worked. I installed "apt-xapian-index", and restarted synaptic. Now when I went into status and showed installed packages I can use the quick filter to only show installed packages containing my search word. Super helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install one extra package -

```
sudo apt-get install apt-xapian-index
```

to get *Quick filter* field between *Properties* and *Search* buttons

[image: search and status in synaptic]

then rebuild the search engine index via command:

```
sudo update-apt-xapian-index -vf
```

and then restart Synaptic.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore (for me using Ubuntu in 22.04).

Comment: @kris Package `apt-xapian-index` seems to me to be installed by default. `apt search apt-xapian-index` returns `apt-xapian-index/jammy,jammy,now 0.51ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]` on my system.